# Is this subspace of $B(\mathcal{H})$ known?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose that I take a fixed ONB of $\mathcal{H}$ let us call it $\{ e_i \}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ and then I define

\begin{align*}
\|T \|_{D} = \sup_{l_i, m_i} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \vert \langle e_{l_i}, T e_{m_i} \rangle \vert 
\end{align*} 
where the supremum is over all pairs of subsequences of $\mathbb{N}$. 
Then look at all $ A \in B(\mathcal{H}) $ such that $\| A \|_{D} < \infty$. On this space it holds that   $\| \cdot \|_{D} $ is a norm and that $ \| A \|_{D}  \leq  \| A \|_{1}$. By considering the matrices that have a small number in the first many element of first row in our fixed basis we can see that the norms are not equivalent.

Does this space have another characterization?

Comment: For "subsequences of $\mathbb N$" to make sense, the set $\mathbb N$ must be considered as a sequence, presumably $(0,1,2,\dots)$. So in a subsequence like $(l_i)$ the terms are in strictly increasing order.  Or should we understand $\mathbb N$ as just a set and "subsequence of $\mathbb N$" as just a sequence of whose terms are in $\mathbb N$, in which case there could be repetitions? Or do you allow non-monotone sequences but prohibit repetitions?

Comment: Good point. I allow non-monotone sequences but prohibit repetitions.

Comment: It looks like a pretty crazy condition ... I'd be surprised if there was any nicer characterization.

Comment: Here is some context. The tracenorm I can estimate in the same way but where I take the supremum over all ONB. Here I am fixed in the computational basis. For normal operators the norms will be the same (namely the trace), but for non-normal operators this norm is sometimes (a lot) smaller.